# Pycharm(specific?) 'int' object is not callable but code works

Tags: python

I'm currently working through hyperskill projects. The way I've done this code probably isn't ideal but i'm just trying to work in lists / classes / objects to stuff as I go.

On Pycharm it highlights all the self.methods under the if statement with " 'int' object is not callable " (or float) - but the code works as expected? Wondering why this would be.

Putting self.everything under the **init** with = None makes the highlighting / warning go away, but the code doesn't work.

This is also my first question, sorry if it is too broad. I tried looking for answers through other questions. Also not sure if I should be pasting all the code as I'm not sure which part is relevant.

```
from math import ceil, floor, pow, log


class LoanCalc:
    options = ['Enter the loan principal:', 'Enter the monthly payment', 'Enter the loan interest:',
               'Enter the number of periods:', 'Enter the annuity payment:']

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def loan_principle(self):
        self.loan_principle = int(input(self.options[0]))

    def monthly_payment(self):
        self.monthly_payment = int(input(self.options[1]))

    def loan_interest(self):
        self.loan_interest = float(input(self.options[2]))

    def i(self):
        self.i = self.loan_interest / (12 * 100)

    def periods(self):
        self.periods = int(input(self.options[3]))

    def a(self):
        self.a = float(input(self.options[4]))

    def main(self):
        inp_options = input('''\
What do you want to calculate?
type "n" - for number of monthly payments,
type "a" for annuity monthly payment amount,
type "p" - for the monthly payment:
''')
        if inp_options == 'n':
            self.loan_principle()
            self.monthly_payment()
            self.loan_interest()
            self. i()
            n_months = log(self.monthly_payment /
                                (self.monthly_payment - self.i * self.loan_principle), 1 + self.i)
            years = 0
            if n_months < 11:
                print(f'It will take {ceil(n_months)} months to repay this loan!')
            elif n_months >= 12:
                while n_months > 11:
                    n_months -= 12
                    years += 1
                print(f'It will take {years} years and {ceil(n_months)} months to repay this loan!')
        elif inp_options == 'p':
            self.a()
            self.periods()
            self.loan_interest()
            self. i()
            loan_principal = self.a / ((self.i * ((1 + self.i) ** self.periods)) / (((1 + self.i) ** self.periods) - 1))
            print(f'Your loan principal = {floor(loan_principal)}!')
        elif inp_options == 'a':
            self.loan_principle()
            self.periods()
            self.loan_interest()
            self. i()
            ann = ceil(self.loan_principle * ((self.i * pow(1 + self.i, self.periods)) /
                                                   (pow(1 + self.i, self.periods) - 1)))
            print(f'Your monthly payment = {ann}!')


loan_calculator = LoanCalc()
loan_calculator.main()
```

Comment: You have methods with the same name as attributes. `def loan_principle` sets an attribute called `self.loan_principle`, which shadows the method name. This will cause errors with more testing in certain circumstances. Give the attributes or methods a different name so they don't clash. To see the error, try calling one of the methods twice in a row.

Comment: Thanks a lot Carcigenicate changing the names fixed it.